# What should be done when deploying Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, dreamhost

I would like to deploy my Rails 3 application. I use [DreamHost](http://www.dreamhost.com/).

My question is what changes should I do to my application before deploying it.

I mean should I change `RAILS_ENV` to `production` somewhere ?

How should I create the database on the server (I use mysql) ? via `rake db:create` RAILS_ENV=production ? Should I create the development database on the server too ?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: The Rails environment will default to production on the server, but as for the rest, what are you using for your deployment script?

Comment: For now I don't have any deployment script. I just copied the files to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to have a deployment script.

Check out [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki). It will save you hours and hours of work. You can remotely migrate the production db with this.

The only database you should have in your production environment is the production database. The development and testing environments should not be accessible.

What does your http server stack look like? Apache? Nginx? Any details will depend on how you have things set up. I answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141151/optimum-os-server-etc-setup-for-rails-production-environment/4141216#4141216) about how my server is configured.

Comment: @pkoch Couldn't say, I've never used it.